# Whenever my Canvas loads it only takes the full width and not the full height

Tags: angular, typescript, canvas

So my Canvas only takes the full width but not the full height.

My component where I try to make the canvas full height and full width:

```
export class AimComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('canvas') myCanvas: ElementRef;
  public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngViewInit();
  }
  ngViewInit(){
    this.context = 
    (<HTMLCanvasElement>this.myCanvas.nativeElement).getContext('2d');
    this.draw();
  }

  draw() {
    this.myCanvas.nativeElement.width = document.body.clientWidth;
    this.myCanvas.nativeElement.height = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `window.innerWith`
and `window.innerHeight` instead of `document.body.clientWidth/clientHeight`, I was able to solve this problem.